# jQuery on Keyup before typing special character

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to autocomplete the username from user email.

```
  $("#useremail").keyup(function () {
    $('#username').val($('#useremail').val()).change();
  });
```

And, for example if user starts typing `useremail` "klajdkljsd@gmail.com"

the username should be entered only till "klajdkljsd@gmail.com"

But, how can I block the text that's entered after @ symbol? So that the username is filled only till "klajdkljsd"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#useremail').on('keyup', function () {
    var user_email = $(this).val().split('@');  // Splits the user_email at the @ char
    var user_name = user_email[0];  // Gets the first key in the array of the splitted items
    $('#username').val(user_name); // Sets the value of #username to user_name
});
```

Or like this - same thing but less code:

```
$('#useremail').on('keyup', function () {
    $('#username').val($(this).val().split('@')[0]);
});
```

Comment: Just something extra... Assuming that calling it 'autocomplete' means they are both form fields, I would add a conditional so that if the user has edited the username, this auto-filling will cease to happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with pattern attribute and some JS modifications to it. Check demo at: http://codepen.io/zvona/pen/LEWZOW

HTML:

```
<p>Username: <input type="text" id="username" pattern="[a-z0-9.]*" /></p>
<p>E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" /></p>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector("#email").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var username = document.querySelector("#username");
  var pattern = new RegExp(username.getAttribute("pattern"), "gi");

  username.value = pattern.exec(this.value);
}, false);
```